# MVC POST Complex Object is NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The Inner Object ExtraData is NULL after Form POST.  I am unable to pass the Object to the Controller.  Need help to figure out what is wrong here.

My Models

```
 public class TestModel
{
    public int ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string SaveMessage { get; set; }
    public bool UserAuthorizedEdit { get; set; }

    public ExtraDataModel EData { get; set; }
}

public class ExtraDataModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
<h2>View1</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDetails", "SaveData", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "RenderProviderVForm", target = "_blank" }))
            {
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClaimNumber)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Key)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SaveMessage)</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EData.ID)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EData.Code)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EData.Desc)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="link-button" value="submit">@Model.ClaimNumber</button>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public void SaveDetails(TestModel tm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Code
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ModelState);
        }

    }
```

The Error on the ModelState says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MvcApplication2.Models.ExtraDataModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)}

[image: QuickWatch Details]

I now got this exception:

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MvcApplication2.Models.ExtraDataModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
```

Here is the generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View1</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<h2>View1</h2>
<form action="/SaveData/SaveDetails?ClaimNumber=123456&amp;Key=40e686ca-1176-4d45-a1dd-33b79b3a9764&amp;SaveMessage=Save%20Me&amp;UserAuthorizedEdit=True&amp;EData=MvcApplication2.Models.ExtraDataModel" id="RenderProviderVForm" method="post" target="_blank"><table>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ClaimNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The ClaimNumber field is required." id="ClaimNumber" name="ClaimNumber" type="text" value="123456" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input id="Key" name="Key" type="text" value="40e686ca-1176-4d45-a1dd-33b79b3a9764" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input id="SaveMessage" name="SaveMessage" type="text" value="Save Me" /></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="EData_ID" name="EData.ID" type="text" value="888888" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input id="EData_Code" name="EData.Code" type="text" value="CD" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>  <input id="EData_Desc" name="EData.Desc" type="text" value="DVD" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="link-button" value="submit">123456</button>            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Now if i have to Edit and Post only **ExtraDataModel** values on the form, what modifications should I have to do.

Comment: You cannot use `@HiddenFor()` to generate the value for a complex object (look at the actual html your generating to understand). You need a hidden input for each property of the model. But what on earth would be the point of sending all that data to the view and then sending it all back again unchanged. If you need it in the POST method, then just get it from the repository again.

Comment: Why are you using a SINGLE Hidden filled to transfer a property of complex class type ? Did you see the generated HTML markup ? You should keep separate hidden fields for each property you need in the HttpPost

Comment: I modified the View and posted the correct code again, the hidden field was just for testing.  
The view has the data , which can be edited and then passed on to the Save method via post, that's the idea

Comment: What are the *name*s of the inputs in the rendered HTML (not the cshtml - what appears in the browser)

Comment: What happens if you change your form declaration to `@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDetails", "SaveData", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "RenderProviderVForm", target = "_blank" }))`   the overload you're using (string,string,object,method,object) has `routeValues` as the first object where you're passing in a Model. I've never seen a BeginForm where the Model is a parameter and it doesn't look right - so try the overload I've suggested (without Model in the parameters).

Comment: That did it, the - Html.BeginForm without the RouteValues works fine